# Failed to load video from tiktok 403 status

Tags: javascript, reactjs, package.json

Good day everyone. I'm quite new to react and have been working on a tiktok project where I am having some problems linking a video properly. It seems like it may have something to do with the local host or .json file. I get a 403 Forbidden error If anyone knows what may help solve this it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

[image: My code as an image]

[image]

Comment: The tiktok server likely doesn't want you to randomly include the video (hence "Forbidden"). Take a look at https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/embed-videos

Comment: Could you please add your code as text instead of as an image?